# Как установить редактор Ace в админке Modx

Tags: modx, ace

Где настроить что бы в админке отображался редактор Ace? Я его установил

Answer (score 1):

В разделе *"Системные настройки"* находим по ключу `which_element_editor` *"Редактор для элементов"* и выбираем, в выпадающем списке, установленный **Ace**

Comment: сделал, но редактор так и не появился

Comment: @Diefair Для шаблонов/сниппетов/чанков этого должно хватить. Если вы редактируете *содержимое* ресурса, то надо снять галочку "использовать html-редактор"